# Calculate pixel from bitmap using ndk

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

How can I calculate total amount of transparent color from a given bitmap using ndk

**Java code:**

```
    static {
    System.loadLibrary("bitmap-processing");
}

public native void calculatePixel(Bitmap bitmap);
```

**Cpp code**

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
Java_com_example_myapplication_CustomLayout_calculatePixel(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,
                                                       jobject bitmap) {
uint8_t *bitmapPixel;

AndroidBitmapInfo info;

if (AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info) < 0) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "bitmap-processing", "ret valude = %d",
                        AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info));
    return NULL;
}

if ((AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, static_cast<void **>((void *) bitmapPixel))) < 0){
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "bitmap-processing", "Bitmap type error");
    return NULL;
}

struct pixel { uint8_t r, g, b, a; };
uint32_t num_transparent = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < info.height; y++) {
    pixel* row = (pixel *)(bitmapPixel + y * info.stride);
    for (int x = 0; x < info.width; x++) {
        const pixel& p = row[x];
        if (p.a == 0)
            num_transparent++;
    }
}

float proportion_transparent = float(num_transparent) / (info.width * info.height);

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Bitmap-processing", "Transparent value : %f", proportion_transparent);

AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
return nullptr;
}
```

As I am new to ndk trying out image processing

You can even rewrite the whole code

Comment: do you really need jni?

Comment: Why are you allocating memory when you already have a pointer to the pixel data in `bitmapPixel`?

Comment: @Michael I was doing some trial and error over there

Comment: @MauricePerry Yes I need jni. Can you help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your pixel format is `RGBA8888`, every fourth byte contains its alpha value.
We can thus walk the bitmap line by line (where every line is `info->stride` **bytes** long), and there are `info->height` lines.

```
uint8_t* bitmapPixel;
if ((AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, (void **)&bitmapPixel)) < 0){
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "bitmap-processing", "Bitmap type error");
    return NULL;
}

struct pixel { uint8_t r, g, b, a; };
uint32_t num_transparent = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < info->height; y++) {
    pixel* row = (pixel *)(bitmapPixel + y * info->stride);
    for (int x = 0; x < info->width; x++) {
        const pixel& p = row[x];
        if (p.a == 0)
            num_transparent++;
    }
}

float proportion_transparent = float(num_transparent) / (info->width * info->height);
```

Don't forget to `AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels` when you're done!

Comment: Even if I just want the count still i have to AndroidBitmap_unclockPixels

Comment: You just copied my answer into your question? I'm not sure what you expect us to do now. If you are wondering about the unlockPixels call:yes, you need to call unlock for every call to lock.

Comment: Ohh I didn't mention 
actully there was a typecast error in bitmapixel so i changed the 
`(void *)&bitmapPixel` to `static_cast<void **>((void *) bitmapPixel)`

Then it was crashing

Comment: Can you just help me out over here and can't see anything in logs

Comment: Edited. The correct expression is `(void **)&bitmapPixel`. I assumed you already had that part working.

Comment: And do you have any documentation for using bitmap with ndk

Comment: The actual "using bitmap with NDK" part is what you found already. Generic image processing is too broad to answer in a comment.